# python tab completion in windows

Tags: python, windows, readline, tab-completion

I'm writing a cross-platform shell like program in python and I'd like to add custom tab-completion actions. On Unix systems I can use the built-in readline module and use code like the following to specify a list of possible completions when I hit the TAB key:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind( 'tab: complete' )
readline.set_completer( ... )
```

How can I do this on Windows? I'd like to avoid relying on 3rd-party packages if possible. If no solution exists is it possible to simply trap TAB key press so that I can implement my own from scratch?

Comment: Just keep in mind, it can be nice to have the TAB key available for indenting (with spaces). I tried out pyreadline but decided to uninstall it because I missed being able to use TAB for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Do u have a look at [PyReadline: a ctypes-based readline for Windows](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro)? Although 3rd-party packages is NOT your option, maybe it's useful for build one's own, isn't it:).

Answer (score 0):

you could look at how [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) does it with pyreadline as well, maybe

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to check out is [readline.py](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/readline.html).