# Tab completion with Python's Cmd.cmd

Tags: autocomplete, python-3.x, tab-completion

After testing a while with the Cmd.cmd framework in python, I noticed a problem I don't know what to do about. Plus I believe to have this working some hours before (or I'm just crazy), so this is even more weird.

I have the following example code, tested on both Windows and Linux systems (so it's not a Windows problem), but tab completion simply doesn't work.

If I use the *exact same* code in Python 2 it does work on the Linux system (not on the Windows one though)

```
import cmd
class Shell ( cmd.Cmd ):    
    def do_test ( self, params ):
        print( 'test: ' + params )

    def do_exit ( self, params ):
        return True

    def do_quit ( self, params ):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Shell()
    x.cmdloop()
```

Do you know why this happens, or what I can do, to make tab completion possible?

Comment: Have you implemented the complete_namehere ?

Comment: The `complete_XY` functions are for the completion of arguments (so when I enter `test f` it could offer me `test foobar`), but the completion of commands is generated automatically from all available `do_XY` functions. Also when I press tab, it simply puts a tab to the command line, whereas nothing should happen when there is no compatible completion (because the functions return an empty list then).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually works for me on Linux on both Python 2 and 3. However, my python setup was compiled with readline support, which is required for it to be automatic per the [cmd documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html). I suspect your Linux Python 3 wasn't compiled with it.

Unfortunately, readline is Unix-specific. See [python tab completion in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081405/python-tab-completion-in-windows) for a discussion of other options on Windows.

Comment: So in this case the developer can only recommend the user to compile their Python setup with readline support (besides implementing their own version of command completion)?

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work on windows after I installed the pyreadline module from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline/2.0

Answer (score 0):

On Mac there is the [Stand-alone GNU readline module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnureadline).
You can get it with `pip install gnureadline`.
It has been tested with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2 and 3.3.